# How to insert DateTime value in PostgreSQL from C#

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework, c#-4.0, pgadmin-4

I want to insert the DateTime value in PostgreSQL from C#
I have fields in my model like this

```
       [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
       public DateTime ApplicationDate { get; set; }

       [Column(TypeName = "jsonb")]
      public StudentInformationtApp StudentInformation { get; set; }
```

The field in JsonB model

```
public DateTime AwaitingDate { get; set; }
```

I am getting the value of `ApplicationDate`  from API is like this `2021-04-02 08:05:45` but when I check in PostgreSQL DB it shows only date `2021-04-02 00:00:000` and for the jsonb fields `AwaitingDate` it stores like this `2021-04-02T08:05:45` What is a T? can I store the exact same value as it comes from my API.
If it comes like this `2021-04-02 08:05:45` store like this `2021-04-02 08:05:45` only

I am using `<PackageReference Include="Npgsql.Bulk" Version="0.9.0"` 
This package for the Bulk insert/Update in PostgreSQL DB https://www.nuget.org/packages/Npgsql.Bulk

Comment: Can you include the code that does the *storing* into the DB?

Comment: I added the package for bulk insert/update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you are using DateTime format in your db for `ApplicationDate`? It seems like you're only storing a date, hence the time being at zero.
T is just a separator between the date and the time. I don't see why this is a problem, because you'll probably [format the date](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings) before showing (after casting it to DateTime).